# Formik - setting dynamic values for select box

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup, formik-material-ui

I have a address form containing country and state field when user selects country i want to fetch state list form backend and update state select box value list.

I have refereed below article for creating form.
https://medium.com/@nphivu414/build-a-multi-step-form-with-react-hooks-formik-yup-and-materialui-fa4f73545598 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBJrH.png)

Comment: You mean preselected state right?

Answer (score 0):

First you can set initial values like below

```
const initialValues = {
    otherValues: '',
    address: {
        line_1: '',
        zip_code: '',
        city: '',
        state: '',
    },
};
```

Then based on this initial value you can initiate state like below:

```
const [initialAddress, updateInitialAddress] = useState(initialValues);
```

After that, in the UseEffect you call API for address and you can update state like below:

```
 //say your response set in "res" variable

 updateInitialAddress({
    otherValues: res.other_values,
    address: {
      line_1: res.line_1,
      zip_code: res.zip_code,
      city: res.city,
      state: res.state,
      },
  });
```

In the formik you can then set:

```
initialValues={initialAddress}
```

And if your Formik Select Dropdown has the same name just like you initialised, then it will be automatically selected in the dropdown.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but how to listen for field value change and access it inside the handler using formik for example - on change of country field call handler read the country value and  pass it to the backend request to fetch state list

Comment: If you are using Formik so you will get updated changed value in "values", please go through formik documentation how to get values for changes value

Answer (score 0):

```
const option = useMemo(() => { 
    return {
        ...formikOption,
        initialValues: selectValue ? selectValue : {name: ""}
        enableReinitialize: true
    }

}, [selectValue]);

<formikComponen  {...option }/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).